# crop, rearrange middle of video frame with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop, video-editing

I have a few hundred video files from a security camera. Let's say here's the full frame:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 2018-10-10 03:02:12 |                         |
+---------------------+                         |
|                         +--------------+      |
|                         | IMPORTANT    |      |
|                         +--------------+      |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I have 2 areas that I want to keep: the date and the inner box.
I know how to crop to either of them, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1120:320:40:60" -c:a copy out.mpg
```

However what I'd like to be able to do is to rearrange the frame to get this in the output:

```
+---------------------+
| 2018-10-10 03:02:12 |
+------+--------------+
| X X X|  IMPORTANT   |
+------+--------------+
```

(X X X would be just black, or if that's hard to do then it can be whatever part of the original video)
Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop the two segments and then stack them vertically.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]split=2[tc][imp];[tc]crop=1120:320:40:60[tc];
                                  [imp]crop=800:400:1300:150,pad=1120:ih:1120-iw:0[imp];
                                  [tc][imp]vstack" -c:a copy out.mpg
```

When stacked vertically, the segments have to be the same width so (black) padding is added.

Comment: I don't understand the commands entirely yet, but it seems the last `[im]` should be a `[imp]`?

Comment: Yes. Corrected.